# Getting this pushState / load content code working

Tags: jquery, html, load, pushstate

I'm trying to get the code I found **here** working on my site. As expected, the site was built as a normal site, sending HTTP requests for page changes, and now i'm trying to upgrade it to full ajax.

The code below executes the pushState, and the back/forward buttons work, but I can't get the content of the page to change. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#loading").show();
    href = $(this).attr("href");

    loadContent(href);

    // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
    history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);
    e.preventDefault();
});

// THIS EVENT MAKES SURE THAT THE BACK/FORWARD BUTTONS WORK AS WELL
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    $("#loading").show();
    console.log("pathname: "+location.pathname);
    loadContent(location.pathname);
};
});

function loadContent(url){
// USES JQUERY TO LOAD THE CONTENT
$.getJSON("post.php", {cid: url, format: 'json'}, function(json) {
    // THIS LOOP PUTS ALL THE CONTENT INTO THE RIGHT PLACES
    $.each(json, function(key, value){
        $('#wrapper').load(href);
    });
});     
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<a href="link1.php"></a>
<a href="link2.php"></a>

<div id="wrapper-outer">
<div id="wrapper">

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit:

Apologies, it seems the link never inserted.

Article: http://www.seomoz.org/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate
Working example: http://html5.gingerhost.com/

Comment: It would make it a lot easier to answer the question if you could put a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: how would it be possible to do that since it's using an ajax request? i couldn't load cross-domain content on there. Besides, I already put up the source site, shouldn't that suffice?

Comment: jsfiddle has an API to simulate AJAX requests: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Comment: The source site link doesn't seem to work. Displays only bold text to me with no link.

Comment: Yea i just noticed that. Apologies, check edit below the code.

Comment: Could you you show your html too?

Comment: please could you post "post.php" or share whole example package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is right:

```
$.getJSON("post.php", {cid: url, format: 'json'}, function(json) {
    $.each(json, function(key, value){
        $('#wrapper').load(href);
    });
});
```

First you do an ajax call to get some json data, then you iterate over that json data (assuming it returns) and on each iteration all you do is make another ajax call to the same href you set earlier, and that's a global variable that you've already sent in the call to loadContent, and would be accessable as `url` instead, no need for a global, and `href` does'nt seem to get a new value from your popstate event, so it will just get the last clicked page anyway  ?

Also, why iterate over json if you don't intend to use the data, and just do the same ajax call on every iteration ?

**EDIT:**

This is going to be a lot of guessing, but try simplifying a little:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        loadContent(href);
        history.pushState({}, '', href);
    });
    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
        loadContent(location.pathname);
    });
});

function loadContent(url) {
    $('#wrapper').load(url);
}
​
```

Your HTML links does not have a path, so make sure they are in the same directory etc.

Comment: i have no idea, I just copied the code from the site lol. Never used this type of ajax loading so, although reading up on it, didn't know what should/shouldn't be changed. If you can modify it for to, please do.

Comment: @CoreyRS - simplified it a little, try it out and keep the console open (F12) to check for errors.

Comment: mwuahahahaha, you're a legend.